# how to redirect to file and fork in background

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection, background-process

i have bash script which running in cron which is outputting to file. however in my script I am running another command which is meant to output to file but is not outputting to file.

**bash**

```
/opt/SP/php7/bin/php /var/httpd/domain/domain.com/scripts/cli-worker-manager.php processQueueAggregateFlows >> /var/httpd/domain/domain.com/scripts/logs/cli-worker-processQueueAggregateFlows.log 2>&1 &
```

`# ps aux | grep cli-worker- | grep php | grep processQueueAggregateFlows`

```
wwwadm   18141  0.0  0.1 456160 29524 ?        S    Mar05   0:08 /opt/SP/php7/bin/php /var/httpd/domain/domain.com/scripts/cli-worker-manager.php processQueueAggregateFlows
```

you can see `>> /var/httpd/domain/domain.com/scripts/logs/cli-worker-processQueueAggregateFlows.log 2>&1` is missing when viewing the `ps`

the cronjob that i run does show up in `ps`

```
# ps aux | grep cli-worker-  | grep "cli-worker-aggregateFlows.sh"
wwwadm    5620  0.0  0.0 117304  1752 ?        Ss   15:19   0:00 /bin/sh -c . ~wwwadm/.bash_profile; /var/httpd/domain/domain.com/scripts/cli-worker-aggregateFlows.sh -e test >> /var/httpd/domain/domain.com/scripts/logs/cli-worker-processQueueAggregateFlows.log 2>&1
```

Comment: i have updated with addition of another `ps`

Comment: @Kusalananda except PHP breaks with `setbuf(3)` tradition and line-buffers stdout regardless of where the output is going